# accessing products in a single division Queryset in a ChainedForeignKey

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

```
src/
|-- grouping
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- models.py
|       
`-- products
    |-- __init__.py
    `-- models.py
```

grouping/models.py

```
from django.db import models

    class Category(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    class ProductDivisions(models.Model):
        categories = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

products/models.py

```
from django.db import models

   class Product(models.Model):
       Pdt_category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
       Pdt_division = ChainedForeignKey(ProductDivisions,
           chained_field="Pdt_category",
           chained_model_field="category",
           show_all=False,
           auto_choose=True,
       sort=True)
```

I tried this but its not producing anything, I wanted to get the products specific to a given division

in products/Views.py

```
def division(request, slug=None):
    single_div= get_object_or_404(ProductDivisions, slug=slug)
    products = Product.objects.filter(Pdt_division=single_div)
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is doing fine and it was my own mistake, I had not entered the products the right way on the admin side, but corrected it. They are coming out very well